# Fast_CGI + PHP7 + NGINX - Blazing fast for cache hits, 10x slower than without any caching for cache misses

Tags: php, performance, caching, nginx, fastcgi

I scanned through my entire site with Screaming Frog SEO Spider and got an average speed of 0.83 URI/second with an empty cache.

With a filled cache the same run through averages 18.69 URI/second.

Without any caching I get around 9 URI/second.

I have no idea what could cause this and can't find other references to this issue on the web. This is something I've experienced with every VPS I've used Fast_CGI with NGINX on. What could cause results like this? Thanks for any leads you can give me to work with.

Comment: What is the cache layer? We talking storing stuff from database on disk or something like that? Or do you mean client 'browser' cache?

Comment: The cache being the fast_cgi cache. No browser caching in the tool I'm using. I should also mention the site being cached is a very simple Wordpress installation.

Comment: If you install a debugging plugin, what kind of number of queries are being executed on the pages? Wordpress doesn't really have a method of query caching out of the box so adding that might help. Also, using Varnish may be an option.

Comment: What makes you think that you should get much higher RPS (requests per second) ? Wordpress is terribly architectured slow software. According to my experience it can generate few pages per secs, not hundreds like modern framework. You suggest cca 8x higher output with caching - which looks consistent. Also it depends on what hardware are you running ...

Comment: @lubosdz I only have 30 pages. Uncached it is faster than cache misses by an order of magnitude. I think you may have misread. I get 10x more throughput with no caching than with an empty cache (100% cache misses), and 2x more throughput with 100% cache hits than I would with no caching.

Why would cache misses take 10x longer than uncached responses?

Comment: Ah, OK, sorry, I misread. Please specify what is your WP cache plugin and cache layer (most likely files). Check your cache directory writing permissions and cache plugin options. To my experience e.g. wp-super-cache works fine but requires little tuning (clear cache & build cache). Aside note - instead of WP I would recommend Joomla, coz it's significantly better architected software, e.g. does not store hardcoded absolute URLs into database or other nasty stuff :-)

Answer (score 0):

1) Disable Wordpress cache plugins if you have them.

2) Disable all other plugins to see if it helps.

3) Enable PHP opcache. Uncomment in your php.ini `opcache.enable=1`.

4) Disable xdebug if you have it (again, in php.ini).

5) Restart nginx & php-fpm.